# We know who Jon Skeet is... who's the troll?

Tags: discussion, unikong

Who (or what) does the troll represent?

[image]

Comment: Is the troll me? I think the troll is me.  The troll is me, isn't it? The troll is me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Given their heads' resemblance to [the classic troll face](https://www.google.com/search?q=troll%20face&tbm=isch), I'd say they represent <del>GnomeSlice</del> generic internet trolls.

Comment: [I'm just going to leave this here.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/157251/evan-carroll)

Comment: @uɐɯsOuɐɥʇɐN Oh right, I forgot about him. What about Your Common Sense as well?

Answer (score 3):

In fact, you, the player, [represent Jon Skeet, the unicorn and the troll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_%28film%29) - the game reflects the fact that the vast majority of stack exchange users who are usually going around asking & answering questions(therefore gathering reps), can also be found casting flaming downvotes and trolling others occasionally.

Answer (score 1):

It represents **you** (i.e., the user behind the player).

That is unless the player is Jon Skeet, in which case it represents [this guy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/4/joel-spolsky).

Answer (score 1):

According to Adam Lear's answer to [Who do the top scores refer to?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/261044/who-do-the-top-scores-refer-to) on Gaming.SE, the trolls represent the top scorers in the leaderboard, but that means that they are also the employees of Stack Exchange.